# Open new thread on each ListBox item using Task

Tags: c#, winforms

This is my play button click event that i want to take each file from my `Listbox` and do the operation:

```
    private void btnPlay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyClass calss = new MyClass();
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            var files = listBoxFiles.Items.Count;
            Parallel.ForEach(files ,
                             new ParallelOptions
                             {
                                 MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10 // limit number of parallel threads here 
                             },
                             file =>
                             {
                                 class.sendBuffer(file, selectedAdapter.PacketDevice, getSpeed(), capinfos.packets);
                             });
        }).ContinueWith(
                 t => { /* when all files processed. Update your UI here */ }
                 , TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext() // to ContinueWith (update UI) from UI thread
             );
    }
```

and i got error that i dont know how to solve in `Parallel.ForEach`:
**Error 1   The type arguments for method 'System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable, System.Threading.Tasks.ParallelOptions, System.Action)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.**

Comment: See `var files = listBoxFiles.Items.Count;`. `files` is an int, not Enumerable. Are you looking for `Parallel.For`

Comment: This probably isn't a good idea. If you have varying amounts of work you need to do on N files, you should take the list of files in a method and dump that into a ConcurrentBag to act as a work queue. Then spin up threads based on your concurrency maximum, that TryTake() from the bag in a loop until the bag is empty. That said you may find your code is IO bound not CPU bound in which case max threads is more about number of drive heads, where the files are physically on disk, etc.

Comment: Can i have code example who to implement it ? (i am a new developer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
var files = listBoxFiles.Items.Count;
```

use

```
var files = listBoxFiles.Items.Cast<String>().ToList();;
```

since you need to loop over the individual items in the ListBox.

I am assuming your listbox is a collection of strings.

Comment: Stil not working: Error 1 The type arguments for method 'System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach<TSource>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, System.Threading.Tasks.ParallelOptions, System.Action<TSource>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.